# Barcodes in postscript

Tags: barcode, postscript

Could you point me a way in which I can render a barcode in PS without the help of any external plugin or class file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [postscriptbarcode](http://github.com/bwipp/postscriptbarcode) and [barcodewriter](http://www.terryburton.co.uk/barcodewriter/).

Comment: I almost recommended Barcode Writer in Pure PostScript by Terry Burton-- then I realized that the project name is postscriptbarcode...

Comment: Despite the lengthy name, Terry Burton's Barcode Writer is a substantial piece of engineering. A ridiculous variety of formats. [Disclaimer: I used a modified version to test my postscript interpreter as it exercises nearly all of the postscript machinery.]

Answer (score 0):

You would draw rectangles spaced and sized accordingly for the barcode symbology you are going to use.

Here is a list of symbologies:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode#Linear_barcodes

If you're implementing this from scratch, I would suggest 2 of 5 or Code 39, as they have the simplest structure.